# How to select all text in a WPF TextBox when focused from codebehind?

Tags: wpf, textbox, selection, onfocus

I would like to set the focus of a WPF `TextBox` from codebehind (not the `TextBox`'s codebehind, but some parent control) and select all text in the `TextBox` from the `TextBox`s codebehind when it receives that focus.

I focus the `TextBox` like this:

```
var scope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(txt);
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(scope, txt);
```

and listen to the event in the `TextBox` like this in the `TextBox`s codebehind:

```
AddHandler(GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SelectAllText), true);
```

and try to select the text like this:

```
private static void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

But the text doesn't get selected. How can I modify this to work as I'd like it to?

Comment: Are you certain that textBox is not null in your SelectAllText handler? Set a breakpoint and step through it.

Comment: You say the `TextBox`'s code behind. If your handler is an instance method of the actual TextBox, why not just call SelectAll() instead of getting the reference from the sender?

Comment: @Steve, I've checked/tried that. The text does get selected according to the selectedText property but it is not being selected in the UI, for whatever reason..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to set `Keyboard` focus on the `TextBox` before selecting the text

Example:

```
private static void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }    
}
```